# Delete string and double redundancy in cell of matlab

Tags: string, matlab, double, redundancy

I have a cell array with two columns. One consists of strings and the other of doubles. I would like to delete all rows, which are redundant.

```
b = cell(4,2);
b{1,1} = 'a';
b{1,2} = 2;
b{2,1} = 'a';
b{2,2} = 1;
b{3,1} = 'b';
b{3,2} = 1;
b{4,1} = 'a';
b{4,2} = 2;
```

So that in the list above the row a 2 will be deleted. Also a sorting would be nice. I found the 'unique' function which tells me that it just works for all string cells. Is there another function for mixed cells?

Best regards
Manuel

Comment: you can merge your double into the string, use unique, then separate them again, since your String does not contain numbers, this should be quite easy to do. You could also do the sorting while they are combined.

Comment: Thank you. I made it that way and it worked

Comment: Consider posting the answer so people with the same issue will find an answer!

Comment: @Manuel I suggest you post your own solution as the answer, so that it might help other people in the future.

Comment: I think there is a file exchange on this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25917-unique-rows-for-a-cell-array

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer thanks to the help I got. Convert the doubles to strings, merge the two strings, unique, separate again and convert the string to double:

```
b = cell(4,2);
b{1,1} = 'a';
b{1,2} = 2;
b{2,1} = 'a';
b{2,2} = 1;
b{3,1} = 'b';
b{3,2} = 1;
b{4,1} = 'a';
b{4,2} = 2;
b

btemp = {};
for i = 1:size(b)   
    [~,columns]=size(btemp);
    btemp{columns+1} = strcat(b{i,1},sprintf('%.3f',b{i,2}));
end
btemp = unique(btemp);
[~,columns]=size(btemp);

b2 = cell(columns,2);
for j = 1:columns
    b2{j,1} = btemp{j}(1);
    b2{j,2} = str2double(btemp{j}(2:end));
end

b2
```